# IEnumerable ViewModel doesn't allow me to access Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, ienumerable

I'm having trouble accessing the properties of `Model` inside my view, when it's an IEnumerable type.

My controller code:

```
//
// GET: /Home/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<CourseworkQuestion> courseworkQuestions = repository.GetCourseworkQuestions(repository.GetUsername()).ToList();
    List<HomeViewModel> model = new List<HomeViewModel>();

    foreach (CourseworkQuestion courseworkQuestion in courseworkQuestions)
    {
        HomeViewModel hvm = new HomeViewModel(courseworkQuestion);
        model.Add(hvm);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And in my view:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<InternalAssessmentViewer.ViewModels.HomeViewModel>>" %>`

I'm sure I've done this before, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a using to get the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace in your page:

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %> //To get all the LINQ extension methods
```

Or fully qualify the reference to `IEnumerable<T>`:
    System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage>

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC. Could you tell me how to do the include please?

Comment: I seem to get other methods and extensions (things like Aggregate<>, All<>, etc.) but not my Properties.